# message board post structure (HTML, 100% height)

Tags: html

I got this structure. I'm trying to basically have the signature at the bottom of post-content regardless of post height (minimum height of avatar or higher). With minimum post height now, message and signature don't take the whole post-content height and signature is at best in middle of post-content.

I have multiple posts per page. Thanks!

```html
<div id="post">
   <div id="avatar" style="float: left;"></div>
   <div id="post-content">
      <div id="message"></div>
      <div id="signature"></div>
   </div>
```

I tried multiple things but it seems no solution really work, e.g. resulting in signature overflowing post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Float your `#post-content` div left and give it a relative position. Then give your `#signature` div an absolute position and a low bottom value (0 will sit flush with the bottom of the container).

```css
#post{
 background:lightblue;
 overflow:hidden;
}

#post-content{
 float:left;
 padding:10px;
}

img{
 display:block;
}

#post::after{
 content:"";
 display:block;
 clear:both;
}

#post{
 position:relative;
}

#signature{
 position:absolute;
 bottom:10px;;
}
```

```html
<div id="post">
    <div id="avatar" style="float: left;">
     <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200" />
    </div>
    <div id="post-content">
        <div id="message">Post content post content  post content.</div>
        <div id="signature">John Doe</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks that is a really clean solution. However, if the post was higher than the image, the result was some text shifting under it. I kept the idea of relative / absolute positioning but applied align-content: stretch; and flex-direction: column; to my post-content div. I also applied flex to have the avatar div and post-content one side by side.

But your answer was the best for the simple example I gave.

Comment: Glad you found a solution. Cheers!